# Select one row of data for multiple row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm currently using Sql server 2016

I've got that example :

```
 ID / TYPE / VALUE
 001 / 10  / EAN13
 001 / 10  / EAN8
 002 / 10  / EAN128
 002 / 10  / EAN13
 003 / 10  / EAN8
 004 / 10  / EAN13
```

I want to have this :

```
 ID / TYPE / VALUE
 001 / 10  / EAN13
 002 / 10  / EAN13
 003 / 10  / EAN8
 004 / 10  / EAN13
```

My current request is :

```
SELECT ID.a,TYPE.a,VALUE.a FROM TABLE.a , TABLE.b 
WHERE ID.a = ID.b  and TYPE.a = TYPE.b AND VALUE = 'EAN13' or VALUE LIKE 'EAN%'
```

I see one option to select only the row I want for each ID : 
Using an order by and only display the 1st row with a ROW.NUMBER but it doesn't seems to work neither.
Could you help me please ? :)

Comment: What is `ID.a` and so on supposed to represent?

Comment: Using ROW_NUMBER is the correct solution.   Please post your attempt to use it, and what error you got.

Comment: @GordonLinoff seems to me that op is using a table alias as a suffix instead of a prefix

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @TabAlleman Row_number will only give me 001 / 10 / EAN13 and only this row , but I want every row that have in priority EAN13 , and if there's no EAN13 we took a random one ^^

Comment: @Rurirm you're wrong.  If you use it correctly, ROW_NUMBER will give you the results you want.   Show us how you used it so we can debug your query.

Comment: @Rurirm check out my solution

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  If you did that, your problem would probably disappear.  You also need to fix the qualified column names:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.TYPE, a.VALUE
FROM TABLE.a a JOIN
     TABLE.b b
     ON a.ID = b.ID  AND a.TYPE = TYPE 
WHERE VALUE = 'EAN13' or VALUE LIKE 'EAN%';
```

Of course, the two `LIKE` expressions are redundant, so you can eliminate the first one:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.TYPE, a.VALUE
FROM TABLE.a a JOIN
     TABLE.b b
     ON a.ID = b.ID  AND a.TYPE = TYPE 
WHERE a.VALUE LIKE 'EAN%';
```

Comment: I agree , a failure from me trying to do an example ^^' Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
; with 
cte     as (
SELECT  t.*
        ,  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.id order by SUBSTRING(t.value, 5, 1) desc) as RN
FROM    table t
)
select  cte.id  
        , cte.type
        , cte.value
from    cte 
where   RN = 1
```